# Attempted to call method expression(java.lang.String) on null context object

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using security in my spring app.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and here is my controller for login:

```
@Configuration
static class ClientWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("fragments/login");
    }
}
```

then I have made menu and there I tried to make logout button:

```
<li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
    <a href="/logout" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
</li>
```

I can **login correctly**, but when it loads the menu it complains with:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 15): Method call: Attempted to call method expression(java.lang.String) on null context object
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the thymeleaf extensions for Spring Security in your dependency list?

Answer (score 16):

Try by adding a question mark at the end of authorization object to check if it is null before using it.

```
${#authorization?.expression('isAuthenticated()')}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment on the question, you may be missing the thymeleaf spring extensions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```